# Uploading image to server convert code from Android to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying replicate the following Android function to iOS Obj C function.
It is for uploading photo album image to our server. User will pick the image from iPhone album and then that image will be uploaded to our server.

I got the Android function for uploading image to the same server. It is working fine on Android. I need to convert that function to iOS Obj C and make it working for iPhone app. Issue is, the below iOS function takes more than 7 mins to get the response back from our server and finally fails uploading image.

- Android:

  protected String uploadImageProcess(String... params) {
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
      HttpURLConnection connection = null;

  ```
  try{

      String attachmentName = "bitmap";
      String attachmentFileName = mFile.getName();
      String crlf = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary =  "*****";
      URL url = new URL(Constants.UPLOAD_URL);

      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
      connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
      connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+mJsessionId);
      connection.setRequestProperty(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, Utils.getAuthorizationHeader());


      connection.connect();

      //int progress = 0;
      int bytesRead = 0;
      byte buf[] = new byte[(int) mFile.length()];
      FileInputStream bufInput = new FileInputStream(mFile);

      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      out.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
      out.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"" + crlf);
      out.writeBytes(crlf);

      while (bytesRead != buf.length) {
          bytesRead += bufInput.read(buf, bytesRead, buf.length - bytesRead);
      }
      out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
      out.flush();
      out.writeBytes(crlf);
      out.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
      out.flush();
      out.close();

      bufInput.close();

      mResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
  ```
- iOS:

  -(void)uploadData :(UIImage *)image {

  ```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

  NSDictionary *_reqHeaderParams = @{kStringAuthorization : [NSString stringWithFormat:kAuthorizationValue,(int)[AppData instance].uid],
                                     kStringCookie : [AppData instance].cookie};
  NSMutableDictionary *header = nil;
  header = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:_reqHeaderParams];
  [header setObject:kAPIKeyValue forKey:kAPIKey];

  [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields: header];

  NSString *boundary = @"*****";
  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);


  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
  [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  // close form
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  // set request body
  [request setHTTPBody:body];

  serverConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [serverConnection start];
  }

   - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {
  returnData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  }

     - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      {
               [returnData appendData:data];
   }

     - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
     {

    if (connection == serverConnection) {
      NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);

     }
   }
  ```

Comment: Are you calling this on the main thread or somewhere in the background? What is the HTTP response and status code? Is the responseString something you expect from your server? Implement connection:didFailWithError: and check the networking error.

Comment: iOS code is in the main thread with NSURLConnection initWithRequest.  Response: {"isSuccess":null,"statusCode":0,"message":null,"fileName":null} - I am supposed to get some value filled here instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you get an actual response from the server your HTTP request works correctly. So basically it must be the data you send that is different. And when you take a closer look it is:

In Android you send this mime header:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + attachmentName + "\";filename=\"" + attachmentFileName + "\"
```

In iOS you send that one instead:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"
```

If you are processing this as a file upload form on the server you are sending the wrong content-disposition header, it should be form-data for iOS as well (doesn't really make sense to send different headers on different platforms when the server-side code is the same for both). Also you are sending different file and field names for the upload which might also be a problem.

As to why it is taking so much time on iOS I can only guess. If you are not doing this on  a background thread I guess it must be the server-side code that takes so long to send a response if it doesn't get the correct form data.

Comment: ok thank you, I've corrected that. I have also observed that if i upload a smaller size image it is uploading quickly, if i upload a image 1 MB and more, it is taking more time to upload. It could be problem on the server end. Anything that I can make it to upload fastly from client app end?